# Stack can't find -lncursesw

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

When I try compiling my Haskell program with Stack, I get the following error:

```
Building executable 'fractal' for fractal-0.1.0.0..
[1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( app/Main.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-2.2.0.1/build/fractal/fractal-tmp/Main.o )
 <command line>: can't load .so/.DLL for: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/8.2.0/../../../../lib/libtinfo.so (-lncursesw: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)

 --  While building custom Setup.hs for package fractal-0.1.0.0 using:
  /home/lorxu/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.2.0.1_ghc-8.4.3 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-2.2.0.1 build lib:fractal exe:fractal --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file -fdiagnostics-color=always"
```

When I compile with GHC directly, it works fine, and libncursesw.so is present in /usr/lib. I'm on Void Linux. Any ideas where Stack is looking?

Comment: Which operating system/distro are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue with the `bindist` Stack has chosen for Void Linux - it normally guesses right, but it can cause issues on some distros. The `tinfo6` variant tries to load `libtinfo.so`, since some distributions provide `ncurses6` through that shared object file. You can try [configuring the variant manually](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#ghc-build) - you'll probably want `standard`. Stack will install a new GHC version if you do that, but it will change what shared object it tries to load for `ncurses`.

#### EDIT:

This was actually caused by [an issue with GHC](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/440) - if the distro links between the various `ncurses` files with a linker *file*, instead of an actual link, GHC won't follow it properly and instead complain that the file doesn't exist. The solution is to replace the linker file with a link to the target.

Comment: This doesn't seem to change anything. It does install a new GHC, but the same error happens.

Comment: What's the state of `libtinfo.*` and `libncursesw.*` in your `/usr/lib`? I can't think exactly why `-lncursesw` would try to load `libtinfo.so` unless `libncursesw` was symlinked to it - and why your system GHC wouldn't have the same issue, unless it was loading `libtinfo.so.6` directly, and that links somewhere else, like `libncursesw.so.6`, as it does on my system (God knows why).

Comment: I have various libtinfo.so.* that link to corresponding libncurses.so.*. Nothing links to libncursesw.so.* as far as I can tell. `stack ghc` doesn't have this issue either, for some reason, but `stack ghci` does.

Comment: Looks like this is an issue with `ghc` that depends on how the distro handles going from `libncurses.so` to `libncursesw.so` : https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/440 . There's a workaround specified in that issue - does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, making libncurses.so a symlink to libncursesw.so fixed the issue. Thanks!